# Drag And Drop a panels in WebPage using javascript ,css, html

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I got the requirement like, In a page there will be 4 panels which can be draggable only in `(2*2)` type , not 1*3 or 1*4 or 4*1. Here i dont know where i went wrong my panels are not able to moving one above another. and if i drag also it must be dragged only in (2*2) order,

http://jsfiddle.net/Navya/zexLM/

Can any one please correct my things hear. I would be very thank full if i get this output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what I *think* you are trying to achieve:

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/stevegreatrex/ZhdHt/5/)

It uses the jQuery UI sortable method to allow dragging of list items into position

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hi Yes, But I need content in to it with <header>,<body> when i create a <ul> tag inside its get messy

Comment: What content do you want to put into each container?

Comment: At the top a header content and in body some Fields in it, and at back a placeholder when we drag . some thing like this          ![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/O42jg.jpg

Comment: At back when i Drag one panel i need a placeholder displaying,and when i click on the button which is in top right i need to resize or panel

Comment: If you have another question then ask it as a separate question on SO